# XML input/output with Fitnesse

Tags: .net, xml, fitnesse, acceptance-testing

I want to create automated tests which accept XML and verify that the XML returned is what was expected.  Also, the end user needs to be able to add new data (XML input + expected XML output) without having to get into the code.

It seems like Fitnesse should be able to do this, but I haven't figured out a good way to do it yet.

Any recommendations?  Tools other than Fitnesse that will work better?  The code which needs tested is in .NET.

Eventually I would like to integrate these test results into a continuous integration server.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fitSharp`](http://fitsharp.github.com) has an `XmlFixture` that will compare Xml results to expected values. See here for more details: http://fitsharp.github.com/Fit/XmlFixture.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have something that will work.  I can create a custom web interface which allows the user to upload XML input and the expected XML output.  Save these to the DB.

Then pull this data from the DB and loop through it in an NUnit test suite.  I can then use XMLUnit to do the actual comparisons.  Pass in the XML input and compare the output to the expected output XML.