# XML input/output with Java fitnesse

Tags: java, xml, fitnesse

There is a .net version of this question answered here: [XML input/output with Fitnesse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248251/xml-input-output-with-fitnesse)

I need to do that with the Java version of Fitnesse and there doesn't seem to be anything similar. I have some tests that accept XML and return XML so I need both the input and the expected output to handle XML in the fields. I've tried various html escaping, but that doesn't seem to get the job done on the comparison side of things. The XML is arbitrary, so I can't parse it into domain objects and compare individual fields (well, I could, but there'd be tons of different object mappings).

Anyone find a way to deal with this issue in a generic way? A custom Java equivalent of the .net solution that exists somewhere?

Comment: Is your goal to have XML in the test page and compare in the test page to the e pelted result? There is an issue when testing XML output in that since order is not necessarily have meaning, so there is a chance the order will change from successive runs. FitNesse does a straight text compare, so that can result in tests failing over a formatting change that does not change the semantics of the XML.  We solved this through writing special fixtures that could query the XML using XPath. I'll go for a more formal answer if you feel this comment is on track for your needs.

Comment: I think I'll have to write something myself. Fitnesse doesn't have an arbitrary compare on the results of an HTTP call. Jut a simple "make sure page X has content Y". In my case, that call returns SOAP (which is XML). The XML ordering is controlled in my case. Ah well, I'll have to build a custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is best solution. You may want to use some XML frameworks e.g. [**XStream**](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) which has very simple API to convert `XML` into `JAVA` objects. Using this, you may want to convert both XML files in JAVA and use JAVA comparison.

Simple steps would be:

1. Define simple Java object (POJO) e.g. `MyXMLObj` to map the XML attributes in Java attributes.
2. Create/generate `equals` method in the above POJO class `MyXMLObj`.
3. Convert your XMLs in Java as :

   ```
   XStream xstream = new XStream();
   XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
   //or
   //XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());

    MyXMLObj myXMLObj1= (MyXMLObj)xstream.fromXML(xml1);
    MyXMLObj myXMLObj2= (MyXMLObj)xstream.fromXML(xml2);
   ```
4. Simply compare the two objects as:

   ```
    if(myXMLObj1.equals(myXMLObj2)){
       System.out.println("Matching");
    }else{
       System.out.println("Not Matching");
    }
   ```

Comment: In a nutshell, the service that's returning the XML is returning a core XML object munged by xslt. The xslt used could be one of dozens depending on the test case so the XML output has dozens of formats as well. So I'd need dozens of POJOs, if I'm understanding your approach correctly.

Comment: If they are different just by attribute then define only one with all possible attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something similar where xml response could change in future or doesn't confirm to a particular style all the time, or xml is not returned as an xml object rather a string is returned etc.

I wrote a generic fixture that would take an xml string and parse it to give us an xml doc object. I would also capture the xml element path and expected value from the wiki and I confirm if expected value is what is stored in the xml or not using xpath.

```
!|ValidateXmlValue                                                                |
|xmlString|xmlElem                                       |getXMLvalue?            |
|$respBody|/root/childnode1/                             |${variable}             |
```

This way users have the flexibility to query node value by simply giving the full path to that node and compare it against an input variable etc. Even if something changes, only test will need to change (you can store path to each xml element in a variable as well, as part of set-up step)